# gSub get Numbers from a String (Corona)

Tags: string, coronasdk

I am using Corona and have strings like

"i spend $350.20 for my car"
"20$ for my dog"
"i used 12.30Euro for my toys"
"simple 8.21 spent"

i like a function that simple filters that numbers
350.20
20
12.30
8.21

please can u help
thanks
chris

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at pattern matching

```
> = string.match("foo 123 bar", '%d%d%d') -- %d matches a digit
123
```

http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial